# Keras seq2seq example save issue

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, seq2seq

.

Hello everyone!

I just tried keras seq2seq example([link](https://blog.keras.io/a-ten-minute-introduction-to-sequence-to-sequence-learning-in-keras.html)).

It works well, but the problem happens when I try to save the trained model.

I had never fixed the code. Is there anyone who already know about this issue?

Please help me!

Error:

```
/home/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/network.
py:872: UserWarning: Layer lstm_2 was passed non-serializable keyword arguments: 
{'initial_state': [<tf.Tensor 'lstm_1/while/Exit_2:0' shape=(?, 128) dtype=float32>
, <tf.Tensor 'lstm_1/while/Exit_3:0' shape=(?, 128) dtype=float32>]}. They will 
not be included in the serialized model (and thus will be missing at 
deserialization time).'. They will not be included '
```

Comment: that's just a warning, are you actually unable to deserialize and run the model?

Comment: Oh, you were right. It was possible to load and run the model and the result is same. I think I had cold feet. Thanks :)